# Twentyfifteen child theme is working on localhost but not on outside server

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I have made a child theme of twentyfifteen theme. I get the theme work in my localhost, but it doesn't work in the outside server. So If I change background color etc. in childtheme style.css it is working in localhost, but in outside server it doesn't work.

Here is my code in **style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Melior
Theme URI:    http://www.meliorvalmennus.fi/themes/twentyfifteenmelior/
Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme for Melior
Author:       Aila Mustonen
Author URI:   http://www.meliorvalmennus.fi
Template:     twentyfifteen
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         light blue, two-columns, left-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-melior
*/
```

and here is my **functions.php**

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
```

I don't understand what's the matter? I don't get any error messages on outside server. I'm a quite new with child themes and wordpress.

Comment: What is LAN? I mean server of OVH-hosting...

Comment: I have still this problem and I can't find any solution. I have tried the same Twenty Fifteen theme and childtheme on other outside server (not in my Computer) and there it works. I can do changes in css and they are showing, but in this server it doesn't work. What could be the difference? Any ideas? I have tried PHP versions 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 - it doesn't help. I used also a plugin (WP Fastest Cache) to delete cache files - nothing helps. Could it even be cache because this has been weeks like this?...? Please help!